# Issue with String Comparison in C while Solving CodeWars Exercise

Tags: c, string, debugging, memory-management

I'm working on a CodeWars exercise where I need to create a function called encode() to replace all lowercase vowels in a given string with numbers following a specific pattern:

- a -> 1
- e -> 2
- i -> 3
- o -> 4
- u -> 5

For example, encode("hello") should return "h2ll4". While I managed to solve the problem, I'm encountering difficulties when comparing the results.

Here is my code :

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *encode(const char *string) {
    char *string_encoded;
    string_encoded = malloc(strlen(string) + 1);
    memcpy(string_encoded, string, strlen(string) + 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) {
        switch (string[i]) {
            case 'a':
                string_encoded[i] = '1';
                break;
            case 'e':
                string_encoded[i] = '2';
                /* code */
                break;
            case 'i':
                string_encoded[i] = '3';
                /* code */
                break;
            case 'o':
                string_encoded[i] = '4';
                /* code */
                break;
            case 'u':
                string_encoded[i] = '5';
                /* code */
                break;
        }
    }
    return string_encoded;
}



int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    char *encoded_string = encode("hello");
    char *valide_encoded_string = "h2ll4";
    printf((encode("hello") == "h2ll4") ? "TRUE\n" : "FALSE\n"); # print FALSE
    printf((encode("hello") == valide_encoded_string ) ? "TRUE\n" : "FALSE\n"); # print FALSE
    //printf((encode("How are you today?") == "H4w 1r2 y45 t4d1y?") ? "TRUE\n" : "FALSE\n");

    
    return 0
}
```

**Problem:**
I'm noticing that whenever I try to compare the results of the encode() function with a valid string, the comparison fails so I thought I could take a look at GDB and both variable are differents. But I don't understand why.

`encoded_string : 0x5555555592a0 "h2ll4"`
`valide_encoded_string : 0x555555556072 "h2ll4"`

For example, when I try to compare encode("hello") with "h2ll4", the comparison returns FALSE. I thought this might be due to the null character ('\0') at the end of the string, but I used strlen() + 1 to copy the string. I'm unsure why the comparison fails in this case.

I would appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue.

Comment: You need to use strcmp to compare string in c.

Comment: you are not just replacing, you are returning another string. Take a look at the assignment to confirm that this is ok. Instead of calling a function (`strcpy` or `memcpy`) you can do the copy/replace in the same loop. You need to `free` the new string before exit. You can not compare strings using `==`. Read the documentation: use `strcmp` or write a function to compare the 2.